# How to define trigger conditions within a ActiveRecord object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model, badge

I'd like to implement a badge system; the user gains badges when doing stuff like "asking questions", "voting"...

However, I'm searching for a solution to define conditions to grant badges. One solution would be that I use an observer model to trigger the badges. But I would use a more elegant way to define the conditions the badge will be granted other than defining this within the observer model.

**Example:**

The user asked five questions each with a rating of at least five. In code I would define a condition like:

`user.questions.keep_if{|q| q.rating >= 5 }.size >= 5`

But I'd like to define this condition within the badge model object. Do you know what a good approach would be?

I'm aware of the [merit badge gem](https://github.com/tute/merit); it is not suitable for my application, otherwise I would have used it by now.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: You could add before save and update handlers.

Comment: Can you explain why that engine is not suitable to your needs?

Comment: The problem was that I thought this gem does not provide levels. But I missed this part and now I found it after investigating the gem in detail. So my problem has been solved for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look into [ActiveRecord callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).

Using a before_save callback would allow you to define a method containing your one-liner above, and test for it every time you save a user to the database

Comment: That is a good and nice way to solve my problem. Thank you! But I will use merit and try if it fits, because I missed the part that it also supports levels.

Comment: After checking the gem out I consider your approach because the gem is not flexible enough for my model structure.